# Bamboo picking some of the dlls from .../facades

Tags: .net, dll, bamboo

I added `system.Reflection` reference in my .Net project and everything worked fine in my local. But when I push my changes to my bamboo build server. I can see these errors:
`CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'E:\agt01\AgentName\Bin\Packages\System.Reflection.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Reflection.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Reflection.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.`

It looks like bamboo is trying to pick those dlls from facades folder in Program Files.

Is it something I am doing wrong or is there any dependent assembly causing this?

Comment: It looks like you added `System.Reflection` as a Nuget package while it is also available as part of .NET Framework. Is there a reason you used Nuget for this dll?

Comment: yeah, I added another nuget package so system.Reflection got installed as a dependency